# R- the function as.POSIXlt() output is not correct

Tags: r

I'm applying  the as.POSIXlt() function to the date below:

```
d2<-"08-12-1990"
d2pos<-as.POSIXlt(d2,format="%d-%m-%y")
d2pos
[1] "2019-12-08 IST"
```

Why is the date getting changed after i apply the as.POSIXlt() function.
Am  i missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the incorrect format. You need a capital Y. Like this:

```
d2<-"08-12-1990"
d2pos<-as.POSIXlt(d2,format="%d-%m-%Y")
d2pos
```

The uncapitalized y is specifying that you have a two digit date and it is reading the 19 and ignoring the 90.

Answer (score 2):

**Modicifation:**

```
d2<-"08-12-1990"
d2pos<-as.POSIXlt(d2,format="%d-%m-%Y")
d2pos
```

As per this [link](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html) y stands for 2 digit and Y stands for 4 digit and there are also other formats

when %y is in given in format it took present century that is 2000 into account and changed the last two digit with the input first two digit

```
d2<-"08-12-15"
d2pos<-as.POSIXlt(d2,format="%d-%m-%y")
d2pos
"2015-12-08 IST"
```